# PHP session randomly expires

Tags: php, html

to begin I'd like to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.
So I have a system where if a user logs in, their username gets stored in `$_SESSION['username']`. On each page I have `session_start();` and I then often check to see `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))` to show different things.

This all works great, except for the fact that either the session expires before the timeout, or the `$_SESSION['username']` variable gets unset before the timeout, causing the system to think that the user needs to be logged out. I would really like to add that this happens **at random!**

I can spend 10 minutes on the website with different intervals between interaction and nothing happens, next thing I know, I get kicked out twice in 3 minutes.

I can verify that `session.cookie_lifetime = 0` (Which means that it won't expire until the browser closes) and that `session.gc_maxlifetime = 1200` (Which doesn't matter, as I have set my session save folder in a different location than tmp).

The only thing I can think of that might be an issue is this code in the login section once the password has been verified:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $usernameInput;
session_write_close();
header("Location: index.php");
```

I know that using header means the session variables do not get saved, as it cuts of the document, but that is why I use `session_write_close();` to save these variables. And please keep in mind: Everything works after this! I can see my username once I get to index.php.

There are some SO threads that result in the user saving session variables and stuff on a database, but I'd rather fix it without having to do that.

**EDIT:**
So I reintroduced a function to count timeout for sessions and that works, but I have made a discovery. I've looked into the `network` section of the browser and in `XHR` I look for the sessions and the cookies and stuff. Something weird happens where the website does a GET request to my `logout.php` file.

So I looked at what could cause this. I have 2 logout buttons that get echo'd by PHP and I gave them each different href links. I narrowed it down to this PHP and HTML. Last time I checked, HTML doesn't automatically go to href's in it's code. And I doubt PHP does this.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            echo "<div class='navProfile navButton'><img class='navProfileIcon' src='images/angerypigeon.jpg' alt=''><h3 class='navProfileUsername'>" . $_SESSION['username'] . "</h3><h3 class='navProfilePosts'>Posts: 102</h3><a class='navProfileLogout' href='php_tools/logoutbutton2.php'>Logout</a></div>";
            echo "<button class=\"modalButton upload navButton\" id=\"uploadButton2\" type=\"button\" name=\"button\" style=\"margin-left: auto\">Upload</button>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<button class='navButton' type=\"button\" name=\"button\" onclick=\"location.href = 'login.php'\">Login</button>";
        }
```

When I check my XHR fields in the browser, it sends a GET request for `logoutbutton2`.
How can I prevent this from happening? I am **not** clicking on the button myself. It gets sent randomly.

Comment: do have a preloading js optimizer in your browser/page ?

Comment: @snitch182 Nope

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not look at all the code I can only speculate. 
What could possibly kill the session at "random".

Maybe you have:

- something like $_SESSION['username']='' or $_SESSION='' in your code. Check it again.
- some code ist spitting some chars in front of session_start ?
- a wierd heuristic adblock-privacy-whatnot-browser plugin blocks your session cookie
- an antivirus firewall on your end does some heuristic cookie killing
- some cleanup job on the server kills the session (very unlikely)
- some antivirus on the server kills the session (very unlikely)
- are you behind a corporate thread management gateway, those things can eat cookies (very unlikely)
- something ist randomly crashing and restarting the server and killing sessions on the way (very unlikely)
- javascript could possibly interfere with your session cookie (very unlikely)

Comment: I checked most of these and they are all not present or interfering with the session.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if `SET-COOKIE` was correctly set in your request header. Check the lifetime (client-side).

---

Sometime files about user session were not created correctly. Check your `session_save_path` and check this folder if new files were made.

- [documentation about session_save_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php).

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have fixed itself. It truly is a random and unpredictable thing..